# JQuery Eval for null JSon object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, visual-studio, eval

I am using Jquery's `$.ajax()` method to retrieve a JSON object from a Webservice. If my data (JSON) is null or undefined, I am getting a

```
Microsoft JScript compilation error :
Expected ']'
```

error for the below line of code:

```
var data1 = eval("(" + msg + ")");
```

This works fine in VS2005 and VS2008 is this a setting in VS2010? or am I doing anything wrong

Comment: Why don't you try using $.getJSON?

Comment: **NEVER** use `eval` for JSON. Additionally, IE is not a good user during development.

Comment: Does it mean that the web service does not always return valid JSON?

Comment: you can also specify json data type with the $.ajax() method. As others have said do not use eval. http://24ways.org/2005/dont-be-eval

Comment: Jumping on the "rag on the OP" band-wagon, there's no such thing as a "JSON Object".  JSON is a string.  If it ceases to become a string, it's a javascript object literal.

Comment: Wow. Wow. Watch out the __bold__ guys. It's safe to use `eval` for parsing JSON if you trust the source.

Comment: Pablo, didn't you hear?  The use of Eval is now black and white as it has become fashionable to hate it!  DOWN WITH EVAL!  DOWN WITH EVAL!

Comment: I guess we should patch this lousy lib that uses `eval` then: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js#L466

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what this has to do with visual studio...

If you're including jQuery you might very well do

```
var data1 = $.parseJSON(msg);
```

Instead of using eval. If that still fires an error, the server response might be malformed, can you please paste it here?

Cheers!